# How to control scrolling of component in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have 4 main components for my React portfolio site called Home, Portfolio, About, Contact. The components are linked in Navigation. If I click on those link, Component appears. But the problem is if I scroll the Portfolio page 50% and click on About. The About page stay automatically scrolled top by 50%. I don't want an automated scroll. Rather I want the component will start from top 0;
I have tried **"css-snap-type"** but it doesn't work.

**How can I solve the problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could solve this using a  react component  that will scroll the window up everytime you click on a different link.

checkout this documentation is pretty straight forward https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/scroll-restoration

If you are using gatsby it comes with and API called called shouldUpdateScroll you could implement it on the gatsby.browser.js

```
const transitionDelay= 500

exports.shouldUpdateScroll = ({
    routerProps: { location }, //location
    getSavedScrollPosition,     //last position on the previous page
}) => {
    if(location.action === 'PUSH'){
        window.setTimeout(()=> window.scrollTo (0,0), transitionDelay) 
    }
    else {
        const savedPosition = getSavedScrollPosition(location)
        window.setTimeout(
            ()=> window.scrollTo((savedPosition || [0,0])),
            transitionDelay
        )
    }
    return false
    }
```

Comment: Hi

I have one product listing page with infinite scroll pagination. Whenever i click on any of the product and goto product detail page and then press browser back button, it will takes me to top of the page instead of where i was. What should i do to retain by old state ?

gatsby version 2.19.18

So your solution will work in my case ?

Answer (score 0):

U need to set window.scrollTo(0, 0) when u click on link so it would start on top of page.